# Printing PDFs quickly from Finder - OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, printing, finder

I've read a few hacks on this and tried a couple but nothing cutting it yet.

Dragging files to desktop printer causes them to print out in portrait when they should be landscape and they therefore don't fit on the page.

Trying [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050410164636852) fails so I suspect the script is outdated for current OS.
[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/200746/printingpdfs-directly-from-finder-in-os-x) is over my head.

- Selecting them and using File, Print only prints first one in the selection.
- Selecting them and using CMD-P gives same result.

In my ideal world: Select files, CMD-P would print each one. I've got a feeling that this did indeed work in Lion.

Comment: Cannot repro the issue. When selecting multiple PDFs, all of them are printed. It simply individually opened documents (unlike when selecting and pressing Cmd-O, when all of them open in the same window)